# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String FloatingDecimal & parseDouble

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane, decimalformat, currency-formatting

I am getting an error. For some reason the error isn't showing up when I compile the code:

//This is the error I get
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Project3A.main(Project3A.java:42)

```
    //Code starts here
    import java.util.scanner;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Locate;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

        public class Project3A
        {
             public static void main(String[] args)
             {
      int numloaves = 0;
      int nummilk = 0;
      double lbscheese = 0.00;
      double brdperloaf = 1.50;
      double milkperqrt = 1.00;
      double chseperlbs = 0.50;
      NumberFormat moneyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of loaves of bread: ");
      int numloaves = sc.nextInt();

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of quarts of milk: ");
      int nummilk = sc.nextInt();

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.ot.println("Enter the number of pounds of cheese: ");
      int chseperlbs = sc.nextInt();

      double brdcst = (numloaves * brdperloaves);
      double mlkcst = (nummilk * milkperqrt);
      double chsecst = (lbscheese * chseperlbs);
      double ttlcost = (brdcst + mlkcst + chsecst);

      String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number of apples");
      double value = Double.parseDouble(" ");

      System.out.println("Cost of Bread: " + brdcst);
      System.out.println("Cost of Milk: " + mlkcst);
      System.out.println("Cost of Cheese: " + chsecst);

      double d = 1.234567;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Cost of bread, milk and cheese is " + df.format(d));
      System.out.println(df.format(d));
      }
}
```

Comment: Your question is about an error, and yet you don't tell us what the error is or where you're seeing it. Please improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't valid Java:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog,"Enter number of apples";
```

When calling any method you must include the appropriate parameters within parenthesis, e.g.

```
myMethodCall(1, 2, 3);
```

Your call uses no parenthesis and doesn't make sense. Read the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to see what parameters you may need.

Comment: I have fixed that, but now I have even more errors@Hovercraft Full of Eels

Comment: @JasvantSinghDosanjh: your program is full of errors suggesting that you're throwing random code at the wall and seeing what sticks, and this will never work as a method of creating a program. I suggest that you scrap all this code and start over. If you can't use an IDE that warns of you of compilation errors immediately, then compile **often**. Do not add new code until all compilation errors are fixed. If you don't do this, you will end up with a mess, like we're seeing here.

Comment: I have an error with my scanner, and my numberformat. And, also Im not just throwing code on an IDE, to see how pretty it looks. I have 2 errors, that have smaller errors included in them, which is my scanner, and number format.@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @JasvantSinghDosanjh: again, you're making the mistake of adding code to already bad code. Don't. Again, start over, and use good practices to avoid doing this -- by compiling early and often, by fixing all compilation errors before trying to add new code and by planning your program before coding it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by bad code, since I am using code given to me, by my professor. I have been to get my errors down to just Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Your professor gave you import statements with capitalization errors? (it's Scanner not scanner)  Time to report them.

Comment: Okay, but once if fix that, I am getting an error, when I run my code, but no error shows up when i compile@HovercraftFullOfEels